# Can I use a GPL v2 software in commercial software?

Tags: licensing, gpl, commercial, gpl-2

I've already gone through the following links and many more:

> [Using a tool under GPL v2 in a commercial application](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7589/using-a-tool-under-gpl-v2-in-a-commercial-application)
>
> [Can I use GPL libraries in a closed source project if only the output is distributed?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/can-i-use-gpl-libraries-in-a-closed-source-project-if-only-the-output-is-distrib)
>
> [GPLv2 - licensing for commercial use](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8064/gplv2-licensing-for-commercial-use)
>
> https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.en.html#DoesFreeSoftwareMeanUsingTheGPL

But still need some clarification.

So I'm developing a commercial software that would require virtual com ports to work. I know there are many great paid tools like `Elitma`, but I stumbled upon `com0com` which is free. But it's licensed under `GPL v2` [https://github.com/paulakg4/com0com/blob/master/license.txt].

I'm not modifying the `com0com` tool but using it as it is. (just using the CLI API, not even any DLL api, to create COM ports). I just need the virtual ports and have nothing else to do with the tool.

**So here are my questions:**

- Can I bundle `com0com` installer along with my application and freely distribute it without having to share my source code ?? I can share the `com0com` source if required, but will I have to share `MY` application source code as well ?
- If yes, is there any other way? Like not bundling the 3rd party installer with my application, but urging the user to download it from a website (maybe my own website) ?
- If I'm developing an independent software that `incidentally` uses the 3rd party tool for some functionality, and not modifying the tool itself, will my work still fall under derivative work ?

Comment: What is your juridiction or legal system? The Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org/) is GPLv2 and used by a lot of commercial software (like Android). Is your client or boss informed? **Did you spoke of that issue to your lawyer?**